# Disable on-screen keyboard in certain textbox using WndProc

Tags: api, winapi, windows-10, vb6

My app has a textbox.
At the mouse up even, the Windows on-screen keyboard is displayed.

I do not want to generally disable the on-screenkeyboard.
I would only like to disable this behaviour for this specific textbox.

How could I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware if this is possible using other programming languages?  From a starting point such as that, you would have established viability of the idea and it would be a relatively easy step from there to applying it to a particular language.  As it is, I can't think of many mechanisms that would directly support this in any language, but I'm only me.